# Tool for Hibernate queries in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: database, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm looking for a tool that could be used in Intellij Idea that would graphically show the output of my database queries in a tablar format. If you know one, please tell me about it

Answer (score 0):

Good news for you. :) IntelliJ Idea provides Hibernate Console [1] out-of-the-box.

[1] http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-hibernate-console.html